# Reading text file into linked list

Tags: c++, c++11

I am working on a program that requires me to read a text file and insert the data into a linked list. I am having difficulty reading the data into the linked list the code compiles, but nothing appears in the output. Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

The text files format is as followed: string int int int int int int int int int int int int

> A 83 140 228 286 426 612 486 577 836 0 0
>   Aaliyah 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 380 215
>
> Aaron 193 208 218 274 279 232 132 36 32 31 41
>
> Abbey 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 537 451 428

use linked list for the internal data structure.

```
linked_list<NameSurferEntry> database;
```

This is the function I use to parse each line in the file.

```
NameSurferEntry::NameSurferEntry(string line){
    vector<string> filelines;

    stringstream inputstringstream;

    year.push_back(1900);
    year.push_back(1910);
    year.push_back(1920);
    year.push_back(1930);
    year.push_back(1940);
    year.push_back(1950);
    year.push_back(1960);
    year.push_back(1970);
    year.push_back(1980);
    year.push_back(1990);
    year.push_back(2000);
    year.push_back(2010);

    while(getline(inputstringstream, line,' ')){
        filelines.push_back(line);
    }
    for(unsigned int i=1; i < filelines.size(); i++){
        cout << year.at(i-1) << " " << filelines.at(0 + 1) << "\n";
    }
        cout << " " << endl;

}

string NameSurferEntry::getName(){
    return name;
}

int NameSurferEntry::getRank(int decade){
    return year.at(decade);
}
```

and this is the function I use to read the text file.

```
NameSurferDataBase::NameSurferDataBase(string filename){
     ifstream input;
    input.open(filename);
    if(!input.is_open()){
        cout << "Not Open";

    }else{
        string temp;
        while(!input.eof()){
            getline(input,temp);
            if(!input.eof()){
                NameSurferEntry entry(temp);
                database.InsertInOrder(entry);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Inser in Order:

```
template <class NODETYPE>
bool linked_list<NODETYPE>::InsertInOrder(NODETYPE value)
{
        if (IsEmpty()) {
                // A variable used to point to data that is being inserted.
                ListNode<NODETYPE> *temp = new ListNode<NODETYPE>;

                if (temp == NULL) return false;

                temp->data = value;

                first = last = current = temp;
                last->next = NULL;
        }
        else if (value >= last->data) {
                return InsertRear(value);
        }
        else if (first->data >= value) {
                return InsertFront(value);
        }
        else {
                // A variable used to point to data that is being inserted.
                ListNode<NODETYPE> *temp = new ListNode<NODETYPE>;

                if (temp == NULL) return false;

                temp->data = value;

                current = first;
                while (current->next->data < temp->data) {
                        current = current->next;
                }
                temp->next = current->next;
                current->next = temp;
                return true;
        }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: And when you used your debugger to execute your code, one line at a time, and examine the values of all variables, as they are used by your code, and thus being able to easily observe your program, as it executes, what observations did you make?

Comment: I would just replace `while(!input.eof()){
            getline(input,temp);` with `while (getline(input,temp))`

Comment: You may need to show the code of InsertInOrder()

Comment: A linked list is a *horrible* (inefficient) datastructure to use. Better read it into a `std::vector`.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I would of preferred to used a std::vector , but my professor insists we use a linked list for this program.

Comment: @drescherjm edited my post to show InsertInOrder()

Comment: Separate the tasks. Just see if you can read the text file. Then see if you can put stuff in the linked list. Printing from a linked list is a totally different task. And whether or not your linked list works on its own has nothing to do with reading a text file, so do it with std::vector, then refactor to use the linked list class.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the following codes you provided:

In NameSurferDatabase:

```
       while(!input.eof()){
            getline(input,temp);
            if(!input.eof()){
                NameSurferEntry entry(temp);
                database.InsertInOrder(entry);
            }
```

You are properly reading 1 line from the file and putting it in a string called "temp". You are then passing the "temp" string to the NameSurferEntry. You are now expecting to this method to dissect the "temp" string.

However, in the NameSurferEntry, you typed this:

```
    stringstream inputstringstream;
    while(getline(inputstringstream, line,' ')){
    filelines.push_back(line);
    }
```

You are declaring a stringstream, which will be empty be default. Then you made a while loop to do getline (inputstringstream, line, ' ') which will take 1 line from inputstringstream and put it variable "line". This replaces the contents of variable "line" with nothing.

Here is how to fix it:

```
    stringstream inputstringstream;
    inputstringstream >> line;
    string temp;
    while(inputstringstream << temp){
    filelines.push_back(temp);
    }
```